# Microsoft TACO update cordova CLI

Tags: node.js, cordova, command-line-interface, taco

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 with last taco version.

The cordova CLI installed is `cordova 6.3.1` but I must to install the plugin `Onesignal` that requires `cli 6.4.0` or higher.

How can I update the cli version?

I tried from console with `npm install -g cordova` but I am getting a lot of errors and no version change.

I tried to install `NodeJS` on my PC and install `cordova` globally to a folder, but when I use `npm install -g cordova`, I get an installation on visual studio taco folder and same errors...

Answer (score 0):

Double click **config.xml**, go on **Platforms** tab then digit version of cordova you want to use in **Cordova CLI** input (6.4.0).

**VS TACO** use a sandboxed version of **nodejs** and **cordova**.

[image: VS Cordova CLI]